# node.js/express/ejs not rendering root page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using node.js, express, and ejs as a development environment.  I've run into an issue where my main page isn't rendered.  However, other pages are rendered.  I get absolutely no return when I access http://127.0.0.1:9999.  However, I get the proper response when I access http://127.0.0.1:9999/about.  I replaced my normal page with a very simple test page to check if there was something wrong it.  Nope.  No change.  I can only conclude that the path '/' (or '') isn't seeing the request.

Can anyone see the problem?  Thanks

app.js

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const app = express();
const port = 9999;

const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, "./views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", viewsPath);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
   console.log("index accessed");
   res.status(200).render("partials/test.ejs");
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res) {
   console.log("about accessed");
   res.status(200).render("partials/test.ejs");
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

test.ejs

```
<h1>This is a test page</h1>
```

I added the following route, and the path is not matched.

```
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
   console.log("* accessed");
   res.status(200).render("partials/test.ejs");
});
```

Comment: Add some console logs inside your route handlers, and then: what does your console say you're hitting when you access `localhost:9999/`, and what does your browser dev tools "network" tab say?

Comment: I bet you have an `index.html` file inside `/public` and the `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));` route (which is defined **before** the `app.get("/", function(req, res) {` route) is matching it first.

Comment: app.get("*", function(req, res) {
   console.log("* accessed");
   res.status(200).render("partials/test.ejs");
});

Comment: Quentin, that was the problem!  Thank you

Comment: @Quentin is right. In my case, that was the problem. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile it is possible to use:

```
app.use(express.static(app_path, { 
    index: false
}));
```

[Credits to](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/issues/8#issuecomment-527609450)